# Confusion with system call

Tags: c, assembly, linker, exec, system-calls

I am trying to understand how a system call is made in x86. I am reading [Smashing the stack for fun and profit](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs161/fa08/papers/stack_smashing.pdf). There is a function given on page 7:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
    char *name[2];
    name[0] = "/bin/sh";
    name[1] = NULL;
    execve(name[0], name, NULL);
}
```

and below the function is given its assembly dump:

Dump of assembler code for function main:

```
0x8000130 : pushl %ebp
0x8000131 : movl %esp,%ebp
0x8000133 : subl $0x8,%esp
0x8000136 : movl $0x80027b8,0xfffffff8(%ebp)
0x800013d : movl $0x0,0xfffffffc(%ebp)
0x8000144 : pushl $0x0
0x8000146 : leal 0xfffffff8(%ebp),%eax
0x8000149 : pushl %eax
0x800014a : movl 0xfffffff8(%ebp),%eax
0x800014d : pushl %eax
0x800014e : call 0x80002bc <__execve> 
0x8000153 : addl $0xc,%esp
0x8000156 : movl %ebp,%esp
0x8000158 : popl %ebp
0x8000159 : ret
```

Dump of assembler code for function __execve:

```
0x80002bc <__execve>: pushl %ebp
0x80002bd <__execve+1>: movl %esp,%ebp
0x80002bf <__execve+3>: pushl %ebx
0x80002c0 <__execve+4>: movl $0xb,%eax
0x80002c5 <__execve+9>: movl 0x8(%ebp),%ebx
0x80002c8 <__execve+12>: movl 0xc(%ebp),%ecx
0x80002cb <__execve+15>: movl 0x10(%ebp),%edx
0x80002ce <__execve+18>: int $0x80
0x80002d0 <__execve+20>: movl %eax,%edx
0x80002d2 <__execve+22>: testl %edx,%edx
0x80002d4 <__execve+24>: jnl 0x80002e6 <__execve+42>
0x80002d6 <__execve+26>: negl %edx
0x80002d8 <__execve+28>: pushl %edx
0x80002d9 <__execve+29>: call 0x8001a34 <__normal_errno_location>
0x80002de <__execve+34>: popl %edx
0x80002df <__execve+35>: movl %edx,(%eax)
0x80002e1 <__execve+37>: movl $0xffffffff,%eax
0x80002e6 <__execve+42>: popl %ebx
0x80002e7 <__execve+43>: movl %ebp,%esp
0x80002e9 <__execve+45>: popl %ebp
0x80002ea <__execve+46>: ret
0x80002eb <__execve+47>: nop
```

However on writing the same code on my machine and compiling with

> gcc test.c -m32 -g -o test -fno-stack-protector -static

and generating the dump with

> objdump -S test > test.dis

I get the following dump for main:

```
void main(){
 8048e24:       55                      push   %ebp
 8048e25:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048e27:       83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
 8048e2a:       83 ec 20                sub    $0x20,%esp
        char *name[2];
        name[0] = "/bin/sh";
 8048e2d:       c7 44 24 18 e8 de 0b    movl   $0x80bdee8,0x18(%esp)
 8048e34:       08
        name[1] = NULL;
 8048e35:       c7 44 24 1c 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0x1c(%esp)
 8048e3c:       00
        execve(name[0], name, NULL);
 8048e3d:       8b 44 24 18             mov    0x18(%esp),%eax
 8048e41:       c7 44 24 08 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0x8(%esp)
 8048e48:       00
 8048e49:       8d 54 24 18             lea    0x18(%esp),%edx
 8048e4d:       89 54 24 04             mov    %edx,0x4(%esp)
 8048e51:       89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
 8048e54:       e8 17 34 02 00          call   806c270 <__execve>
}
```

And for __execve:

```
0806c270 <__execve>:
 806c270:       53                      push   %ebx
 806c271:       8b 54 24 10             mov    0x10(%esp),%edx
 806c275:       8b 4c 24 0c             mov    0xc(%esp),%ecx
 806c279:       8b 5c 24 08             mov    0x8(%esp),%ebx
 806c27d:       b8 0b 00 00 00          mov    $0xb,%eax
 806c282:       ff 15 f0 99 0e 08       call   *0x80e99f0
 806c288:       3d 00 f0 ff ff          cmp    $0xfffff000,%eax
 806c28d:       77 02                   ja     806c291 <__execve+0x21>
 806c28f:       5b                      pop    %ebx
 806c290:       c3                      ret
 806c291:       c7 c2 e8 ff ff ff       mov    $0xffffffe8,%edx
 806c297:       f7 d8                   neg    %eax
 806c299:       65 89 02                mov    %eax,%gs:(%edx)
 806c29c:       83 c8 ff                or     $0xffffffff,%eax
 806c29f:       5b                      pop    %ebx
 806c2a0:       c3                      ret
 806c2a1:       66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
 806c2a3:       66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
 806c2a5:       66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
 806c2a7:       66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
 806c2a9:       66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
 806c2ab:       66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
 806c2ad:       66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
 806c2af:       90                      nop
```

I understand that the article is very old so it may not match exactly with the current standards. In fact i am able make sense of most of the differences. Here is what is bothering me:

From what I know: to make the exec system call I need to put the arguments in specific registers and call the instruction

> int 0x80

to send an interrupt. I can see this instruction at address **0x80002ce** in the dump given in the article. But I cannot find the same instruction in mine. In place of it I find

> call   *0x80e99f0

and the address **0x80e99f0** doesn't even exists in my dump. What am I missing here? What is the point of a ***** before **0x80e99f0**. Is the address **0x80e99f0** being dynamically loaded at runtime? If it is true then what is the use of **-static** flag during compilation and what can I do to make the dump similar to that of the article?

I am running 64 bit ubuntu 14.04 on Intel processor

### Edit after getting suggestion to run objdump with -DS flag:

<s>I finally get the hidden address:</s>

```
080e99f0 <_dl_sysinfo>:
 80e99f0:       70 ed                   jo     80e99df <_dl_load_lock+0x7>
 80e99f2:       06                      push   %es
 80e99f3:       08 b0 a6 09 08 07       or     %dh,0x70809a6(%eax)
```

but still can't make any sense.

The address in **jo 80e99df** points again to something that is hidden in between these lines:

```
080e99d8 <_dl_load_lock>:
        ...
 80e99e4:       01 00                   add    %eax,(%eax)
        ...
```

As evident from the answer the code actually jumps to the address present in memory location **0x80e99f0** which eventually points to `int $0x80` instruction.

Comment: You have to interpret the data at 80e99f0 as _data_, not as instructions. You get `70 ed 06 08` from that, which is memory address 806ed70

Comment: Why are you defining `void main()` rather than the correct `int main(void)`?

Comment: @KeithThompson I didn't think about it. In the original article its `void main()` only. Does it makes a difference to what my problem is?

Comment: It's probably not relevant to your problem. But `void main()` is not portable, and there is no reason to use it rather than the correct and portable `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `objdump -DS` or `objdump -sS` to include the address 0x80e99f0 in your dump.

Local example:

```
0806bf70 <__execve>:
...
806bf82:       ff 15 10 a3 0e 08       call   *0x80ea310
```

At address 0x80ea310 (shown with `objdump -sS`):

```
80ea310 10ea0608 60a60908 07000000 7f030000
```

`10ea0608` is address 0x806ea10 little-endian in memory.

You will then see, that the address of `_dl_sysinfo_int80` is located there:

```
0806ea10 <_dl_sysinfo_int80>:
 806ea10:       cd 80                   int    $0x80
 806ea12:       c3                      ret
```

which calls the software interrupt 0x80 (executes the syscall) and returns to the caller then.

call *0x80ea310 is therefore really calling 0x806ea10 (dereferencing a pointer)

Comment: I edited the question with inputs from your suggestions. I still cant't make any sense..

Comment: Thank you. I got what you are trying to say. Why is gcc doing this all complications. Any ideas? And what exactly did -D flag do to the objdump command.

Comment: This is standard linking procedure, dereference an address in the linkage table which is filled on executable _linkage_, not when compiling the object files.

Comment: If I straightaway call `int $0x80` after filling the appropriate registers. Will it still work? I think it should

Comment: You could indeed change the contents of `806bf82` to `cd 80 90 90 90 90` (int $0x80 nop nop nop nop) and it would still work

Answer (score 3):

Traditionally, Linux used interrupt 0x80 to invoke system calls. Since the PentiumPro, there is an alternative way to invoke a system call: using the SYSENTER instruction (AMD also has its own SYSCALL instruction). This is a more efficient way to invoke a system call.

**Choosing which syscall mechanism to use**

The linux kernel and glibc have a mechanism to choose between the different ways to invoke a system call.

The kernel sets up a virtual shared library for each process, it's called the VDSO (virtual dynamic shared object), which you can see in the output of `cat /proc/<pid>/maps`:

```
$ cat /proc/self/maps
08048000-0804c000 r-xp 00000000 03:04 1553592    /bin/cat
0804c000-0804d000 rw-p 00003000 03:04 1553592    /bin/cat
[...]
b7ee8000-b7ee9000 r-xp b7ee8000 00:00 0          [vdso]
[...]
```

This vdso, among other things, contains an appropriate system call invocation sequence for the CPU in use, e.g:

```
ffffe414 <__kernel_vsyscall>:
ffffe414:       51                      push   %ecx        ; \
ffffe415:       52                      push   %edx        ; > save registers
ffffe416:       55                      push   %ebp        ; /
ffffe417:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp   ; save stack pointer
ffffe419:       0f 34                   sysenter           ; invoke system call
ffffe41b:       90                      nop
ffffe41c:       90                      nop                ; the kernel will usually
ffffe41d:       90                      nop                ; return to the insn just
ffffe41e:       90                      nop                ; past the jmp, but if the
ffffe41f:       90                      nop                ; system call was interrupted
ffffe420:       90                      nop                ; and needs to be restarted
ffffe421:       90                      nop                ; it will return to this jmp
ffffe422:       eb f3                   jmp    ffffe417 <__kernel_vsyscall+0x3>
ffffe424:       5d                      pop    %ebp        ; \
ffffe425:       5a                      pop    %edx        ; > restore registers
ffffe426:       59                      pop    %ecx        ; /
ffffe427:       c3                      ret                ; return to caller
```

In `arch/x86/vdso/vdso32/` there are implementations using `int 0x80`, `sysenter` and `syscall`, the kernel selects the appropriate one.

To let userspace know that there is a vdso, and where it is located, the kernel sets `AT_SYSINFO` and `AT_SYSINFO_EHDR` entries in the auxiliary vector (`auxv`, the 4th argument to `main()`, after `argc, argv, envp`, which is used to pass some information from the kernel to newly started processes). `AT_SYSINFO_EHDR` points to the ELF header of the vdso, `AT_SYSINFO` points to the vsyscall implementation:

```
$ LD_SHOW_AUXV=1 id    # tell the dynamic linker ld.so to output auxv values
AT_SYSINFO:      0xb7fd4414
AT_SYSINFO_EHDR: 0xb7fd4000
[...]
```

glibc uses this information to locate the `vsyscall`. It stores it into the dynamic loader global `_dl_sysinfo`, e.g.:

```
glibc-2.16.0/elf/dl-support.c:_dl_aux_init():
ifdef NEED_DL_SYSINFO
  case AT_SYSINFO:
    GL(dl_sysinfo) = av->a_un.a_val;
    break;
#endif
#if defined NEED_DL_SYSINFO || defined NEED_DL_SYSINFO_DSO
  case AT_SYSINFO_EHDR:
    GL(dl_sysinfo_dso) = (void *) av->a_un.a_val;
    break;
#endif

glibc-2.16.0/elf/dl-sysdep.c:_dl_sysdep_start()

glibc-2.16.0/elf/rtld.c:dl_main:
GLRO(dl_sysinfo) = GLRO(dl_sysinfo_dso)->e_entry + l->l_addr;
```

and in a field in the header of the TCB (thread control block):

```
glibc-2.16.0/nptl/sysdeps/i386/tls.h

_head->sysinfo = GLRO(dl_sysinfo)
```

If the kernel is old and doesn't provide a vdso, glibc provides a default implementation for `_dl_sysinfo`:

```
.hidden _dl_sysinfo_int80:
int $0x80
ret
```

When a program is compiled against glibc, depending on circumstances, a choice is made between different ways of invoking a system call:

```
glibc-2.16.0/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/sysdep.h:
/* The original calling convention for system calls on Linux/i386 is
   to use int $0x80.  */
#ifdef I386_USE_SYSENTER
# ifdef SHARED
#  define ENTER_KERNEL call *%gs:SYSINFO_OFFSET
# else
#  define ENTER_KERNEL call *_dl_sysinfo
# endif
#else
# define ENTER_KERNEL int $0x80
#endif
```

- `int 0x80` ← the traditional way
- `call *%gs:offsetof(tcb_head_t, sysinfo)` ← `%gs` points to the TCB, so this jumps indirectly through the pointer to vsyscall stored in the TCB
- `call *_dl_sysinfo` ← this jumps indirectly through the global variable

So, in x86:

```
                    system call
                         ↓
int 0x80 / call *%gs:0x10 / call *_dl_sysinfo
                    │            │
                    ╰─┬──────────┼─────────╮ 
                      ↓          ↓         ↓
         (in vdso) int 0x80 / sysenter / syscall
```